# Xcode: build failed: error message

Tags: ios, xcode, build, compiler-errors

I am building and running my Xcode app but I get a build failed message on account of the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFAccountManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFApplication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFAuthenticationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFRestAPI", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in OrderVC.o
      objc-class-ref in PerformanceVC.o
      objc-class-ref in CustomerDetailsVC.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_kSFLoginHostChangedNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate init] in AppDelegate.o
      -[AppDelegate dealloc] in AppDelegate.o
  "_kSFUserLogoutNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate init] in AppDelegate.o
      -[AppDelegate dealloc] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I resolve this/these issue(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would set `Architectures` in your project to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)`, which will do the right thing for both iOS builds and OS X / simulator builds.

The problem is that your library is not built for x86_64, but your project is trying to build for both i386 and x86_64, so the link step fails.  Apple changed the default architecture in Xcode 5.1 to include 64-bit architectures.

See these other questions for more info:

- [Xcode Mach-O Linker errors with 64-bit simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496516/xcode-mach-o-linker-errors-with-64-bit-simulator/22499833#22499833)
- [Missing X86 code in iOS build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535955/missing-x86-code-in-ios-build/22538809#22538809)

Comment: Thanks for the insight and solution. Worked first time perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Click on your project in xcode and go to build settings -> valid architectures and remove `arm64` also change `Standard Architectures` to armv7 and armv7s .Clean and rerun the project

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to include the Salesforce Mobile SDK iOS framework in your project.